# Method to check if a test ID has already been used in a test flow?

Tags: origen-sdk

When looking at the [test program flow creation guide](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/), I wondered if there was a method to determine if a test ID has already been used.  I am using many enumerators in my flows and get this error when there are duplicate IDs:

```
[ERROR]      71.979[0.000]   || Test ID scan_delay_testmode1_nclk_1cyc_pmax is defined more than once in flow scan_flow:
```

Would be nice to be able to trap for this with a method.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but you can get the IDs used so far via:

```rb
ATP::AST::Extractor.new.process(flow.atp.raw, [:id]).map { |node| node.to_a[0] }
```

A PR would be accepted to expose something more elegant like:

```rb
flow.atp.ids  # => [:id1, :id2]
```

The `ids` method would simply contain the above and could be added to here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/atp/blob/master/lib/atp/flow.rb

---

Update:

As of this PR, https://github.com/Origen-SDK/atp/pull/9, you can now call:

```rb
flow.ids      # => [:id1 ,:id2]
```

Comment: is there a Hash/Array that could be queried in a new method?

Comment: Not quite that simple, though I've updated my answer with an approach that works